# ErrUchIsDown: You process has been killed because of using too much resources

Tags: python-3.x

why memoryerror

```
def safe_code(equation):
    n=-1
    for i in range(10):
            if eval(equation.replace('#',str(i))):
                n=i  
                break
    return n

    equation ="##*##==312#"
```

ErrUchIsDown: You process has been killed because of using too much resources

Comment: Where is this being run? That doesn't sound like a standard Python error.

Comment: This code just immediately returns -1 for me. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I tested numbers up to 1e7 and couldn't find a number that satisfies the equation, so I'm not sure what you're going for here. Your equation template string may be wrong.

Comment: problem from CheciO https://py.checkio.org/

Comment: You might want to run it on your own machine first. And I've checked up to 190 million and still haven't found an answer. Again, you may want to make sure you have the question correct.

Comment: when I test by using Anaconda, it works, but when I test in "checkio", it couldnot work. Other problems cause same too.

Comment: thanks, I solve it.